# Получить данные из базы данных (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Добрый день. 
Дано задание: 
есть html-страничка, на которой выведены поля для задания критерия поиска.
Надо получить данные из базы данных, используя значения из вышеуказанных полей (их много и не все обязательные).
Есть большой опыт получения данных из БД через .net, но здесь идет пока чистый html & js (+ bootstrap & jquery).
В задании прозвучала фраза - создать api  для получения данных. С этим (api) нет опыта работы. 
Буду признательна за указания направления действий. Где можно найти информацию по этому вопросу - для изучения?
Так же при обсуждении задания прозвучала мысль об использовании Aurelia. Но я пока не понимаю, как этот фреймворк тут применять. Пока речь не идет о написании портала, на данном этапе просто нужна html-страничка, на которой будет происходить поиск данных из БД.

Comment: @Darth тут автор вопроса использовала ваш ответ-комментарий, но не может его отметить галочкой. Может быть, опубликуете что-нибудь?

Comment: @NickVolynkin перенёс в ответ as is

Answer (score 4):

Вам действительно понадобится сервер. Самый простой и классический вариант, который легко организовать на любом хостинге: AJAX + php + MySQL.

Можно написать сервер на .net, но надо будет организовать его работу - для простых задач это лишнее усложнение. А для себя для такой задачи я выбрал бы сервер на Node JS + Mongo, так как их синтаксис - тот же самый js, их связка без проблем работает с большой нагрузкой, а создание и запросы бд на монго просты и интуитивны.

Единственная сложность - организовать сервер на ноде или использовать heroku, так как готовых простых решений/хостингов для ноды нету. Под апи я так понимаю REST. В простейшем варианте на php вам нужно будет создать страничку в корневой папке сайта на сервере search.php, которая бы отвечала на GET запрос вида:

```
yoursite.ru/search.php?city=bobruisk&street=lenina
```

высылая какие-нибудь данные в каком-либо виде, например в JSON:

```
[{
            "owner": "Осипенко Олег Эдуардович",
            "rooms": "3",
            "price": "$130",
            "adress": "Республика Беларусь, г. Бобруйск, ул. Ленина 13",
            "email": "osipenko123@mail.ru",
},{
            "owner": "Иванов Иван Иванович",
            "rooms": "2",
            "price": "$150",
            "adress": "Республика Беларусь, г. Бобруйск, ул. Ленина 4",
            "email": "ivanov1992@mail.ru",
}]
```

Смысл в том, вы на сайте с помощью AJAX отправляете запрос

`GET yoursite.ru/search.php?city=bobruisk&street=lenina`

сервер получает запрос, парсит параметры

`city=bobruisk&street=lenina`

подключается к базе данных и ищет в базе соответствия с помощью запросов к базе. Если нашел необходимые (в моем случае квартиры) данные, то выдает ответ со статусом 200, в котором в JSON хранятся квартиры. Вы парсите ответ с помощью javascript и собираете из них блоки или таблицу в HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Вам понадобиться сервачок. Если знаете .net, то можете попробовать сделать [api на нём](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api).

Или, как вариант, можно использовать [Websql](http://xozblog.ru/2012/10/to-do-list/), но оно [deprecated](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) и поэтому у него [поддержка хромает](http://caniuse.com/#search=websql)

Comment: **Darth** Спасибо! Реализовала Ваш вариант - api на .net.